# J Language web programming

Tags: j

Is there a web framework to create websites using J on a server? Last time I checked there was a simple CGI package with tagged J code in line. Are there any plans to offer something more comprehensive?

Comment: J has its own web server ([jhs](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Guides/JHS/Install)) where you can run J scripts.

Comment: There's a lot implied in your question. Are you just curious? Or do you have a project in mind? Do you really want to build a site in J? Or just do some backend data processing?

Comment: You might have more luck finding an answer from the J mailing lists, particularly the [source](http://www.jsoftware.com/mailman/listinfo/source) or [programming](http://www.jsoftware.com/mailman/listinfo/programming) lists.

Comment: It would be for site experimentation - fastcgi similar to PHP/HTML on the same page with J in place of PHP.

Comment: I checked out the state of JHS - the web server. It looks very good now, AJAX, markdown, javascript etc. and my guess is eventually it will add in fastcgi capability and maybe even hosting. There are already a few fastcgi scripts available to review.

Answer (score -1):

Well ,you can't make site with J (on server or not)
J is not support at HTML for run and make your own site.